# Django Constructors and Mixins

Tags: python, django

I have a model that looks like this:

```
class Base(models.Model):
  pass

class Mixin1(Base):
  active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Mixin2(Base):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=False,null=False)

class Organization(Mixin1, Mixin2, Base):
  pass
```

This works fine:

```
organization = Organization(name='name')
organization.active = True
organization.save()
```

But this does not:

```
organization = Organization(name='name', active=True)
organization.save()
```

Django errors out on the constructor with:

```
TypeError: 'active' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

a Is there something I'm missing about mixins?

**Update of what I am seeing:**
Using a fresh PostgreSQL database and a fresh shell.

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep  5 2012, 20:48:07) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 ((tags/Apple/clang-421.0.60))] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from core.models.organizations import Organization
>>> org1 = Organization(name='name')
>>> org1
<Organization: name>
>>> org1.active = True
>>> org1
<Organization: name>
>>> org1.active
True
>>> org2 = Organization(name='org2',active=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<myprojectpath>/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 367, in __init__
    raise TypeError("'%s' is an invalid keyword argument for this function" % kwargs.keys()[0])
TypeError: 'active' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
>>>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works, I just tried.

```
In [2]: model = Model(name='name')
In [3]: model.active = True
In [4]: model.save()

In [5]: model = Model(name='name2', active=True)
In [6]: model.save()

In [9]: Model.objects.all()
Out[9]: [<Model: Model object>, <Model: Model object>]
```

The problem should be somewhere else.

Comment: OK, let me see if there is something else going on in the code I edited down.  Thanks.

Comment: What kind of database are you using?  Mine is PostgreSQL.

Comment: Try to sync the database and to restart the shell instance. If you edit your code after a shell is started, the shell won't know about the changes.

Comment: Sqlite, but that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: What is the version of Django

Comment: From my requirements.txt file: Django==1.4.1

Answer (score 2):

I had a stale .pyc file hanging around screwing things up.  I changed a file from organization.py to organizations.py.  For some reason, organization.pyc stuck around and was being imported by another model file.  Frustrating.

Comment: You can use clean_pyc from django extensions to prevent further problems.

Comment: Excellent suggestion on clean_pyc -- esp. since I am already using django-extensions.